# SlickGrid onCellChange after edits shown in example 7

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

If I add the following code to SlickGrid example 7:

```
grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function(e,args) 
{
  alert("here");
});
```

The alert appears if I update the text field, 'Title'.  It does not when I update the 'Priority' field, which is being used to demonstrate click to toggle values.  Clicks are captured with this code.

```
    grid.onClick.subscribe(function(e) {
       var cell = grid.getCellFromEvent(e);
       if (columns[cell.cell].id == "priority") {
          var states = { "Low": "Medium", "Medium": "High", "High": "Low" };
          data[cell.row].priority = states[data[cell.row].priority];
          grid.updateRow(cell.row);
          e.stopPropagation();
       }
    });
```

Question:
How do I trigger onCellChange when the 'Priority' value changes?

Thank you to anyone who can help.
John.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out.  Thanks Tin for the tip.

If you have the same problem, simply duplicate your save code in the onClick subscribe, sending the data from data[cell.row].

Comment: The comment above by the op does not answer the original question - it might solve the reason the question was generated - but not the question.

Answer (score 1):

Makes perfect sense to me.
The event is raised by the grid only if the action was initiated within the grid. 
In your second example, you are making the change yourself directly against the data source by intercepting specific click events.

Comment: Any advice on how to accomplish this?  The grid.onClick.subscribe is from the example, but they don't follow up with how to save.  Everything I see says to save with onCellChange.subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

How about just using JQuery with the `$(#priority).change` selector?

So here is how it would look (or something similar):

```
$("#priority").change(function(e) {
    var cell = grid.getCellFromEvent(e);
    var states = { "Low": "Medium", "Medium": "High", "High": "Low" };
    data[cell.row].priority = states[data[cell.row].priority];
    grid.updateRow(cell.row);
    e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

You probably want to change it to use a class instead of an id though, as each DOM id is supposed to remain unique per page.